# Recyclerview gets recreated when fragment is recreated coming to foreground

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-livedata, observer-pattern

I have a Fragment which has a `RecyclerView` showing a list from an observer which observes for changes in the list data from Room db. It works like this - `FragmentA` has list `RecyclerView` and when user clicks on an item, it opens(replaces) another `FragmentB` which is a list detail fragment where user can edit the list detail item and save it(update in db), and `LiveData` will do it's work and update the list. But when I press back button, `FragmentA`'s view is recreated and another identical observer gets subscribed as shown in the code below -

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    setupUI(view);

    viewModel.getInspections().observe(this, inspectionsList -> {
        setUpMainAdapter(inspectionsList); //setting Recyclerview adapter on recyclerview.
    })
}
```

I found a solution to this problem [in this article](https://medium.com/@jacquesgiraudel/problem-with-restoring-fragments-from-the-backstack-945dc3f7f5a5), where it is written to use `getViewLifecycleOwner()` instead of `this` so that the observers are also unsubscribed when the fragment view hierarchy is changed. 
Now my problem is, if I come back to `FragmentA` from `FragmentB`, `setUpMainAdapter()` is getting called again, and a new adapter is being set on the recyclerview. While I check the old adapter instance is still alive. If I do `adapter.notifyItemChanged(position)` it doesn't work and the recyclerview doesn't have anything to show (because the view got recreated). So, is setting up the adapter to the recyclerview is the right approach here? Because it feels odd to set up the main adapter again and again and not being able to use adapter's notify methods to just update an item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> use `getViewLifecycleOwner()` instead of this so that the observers are also unsubscribed when the fragment view hierarchy is changed.

This is fundamental. When you register an observer in other frameworks like RxJava, you always need to unsubscribe it eventually. With LiveData, the lifecycle owner does this for you. But when you use `this` as the lifecycle owner, observers are only removed when the fragment is destroyed, but they aren't when the view is destroyed! So you end up with multiple observers referencing destroyed views, which will created memory leaks.

> So, is setting up the adapter to the recyclerview is the right approach here?

I usually create my adapters in `onViewCreated`, but I think you should be fine reusing the old adapter if you make sure to set it again on your new RecyclerView.

Comment: but I do need to set the _old_ `adapter` on _new_ `RecyclerView` everytime?

Comment: Yes, create your adapter in `onCreate` and set it in `onViewCreated`.

Comment: I just saw [this article](https://charlesmuchene.hashnode.dev/a-subtle-memory-leak-fragment-recyclerview-and-its-adapter-ck805s7jd03frzns17uapi3vh) and I think recreating the adapter every time in `onCreateView` is the best option to avoid memory leaks. The problem is that the adapter has observers that will still reference the RecyclerView after it should have been destroyed in `onDestroyView`...